# Occasional ComponentNotFoundException under test load

Tags: wicket

When testing our Wicket application (Wicket 7.2.0 on WAS 8.5, Linux) we do experience occasional ComponentNotFoundExceptions under test load. This Exception does not occur under normal user load. Has anyone experienced this kind of error yet?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that the user (browser, load testing tool) makes a request to some component or behavior added to a component but this component is not in the page hierarchy.

Apparently the problem happens only when the application is used by many users (load test) and there is a bug in the application.